# Kibana wildcard search contains text

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Trying to serach a field that contains some text in Kibana logs:
`thread:*mythread*`

Kibana reports this is invalid.

[Kibana docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html) show only the syntax where field starts with some value `thread:mythread*`, and this works correctly. The issue is when field value starts with `*`.

How can I search fields containing some text?